# Update item in another site collection in sharepoint 2013

Tags: json, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I need to update item in another site collection according to this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/update-list-item-across-site-collection-using-rest-services-and-copy-files-from-one-library-to-another-using-sp-services) I make my code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var otherSiteUrl = "<sitecollectionurl>";
        var listName = "TestList";
        var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
        var item = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": itemType
            },
            "Title": "updated title"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: otherSiteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
            type: "POST", 
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (contextData) {
                alert(contextData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue);
                $.ajax({
                    url: otherSiteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?@target='" + otherSiteUrl + "'",
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    data: JSON.stringify(item),
                    async: false,
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": contextData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
    function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
        return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
    }
</script>
```

I used

> "X-RequestDigest":
>   contextData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue

after that I chenge ajax header like

> "X-RequestDigest": 
>   $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(contextData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue)

for both `RequestDigest` I got this error:

> Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content
>   after that I chenge ajax header as

How can I update item successfully in another site collection with api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually, I can edit item in another site collection.I just little change in my code.

first, most important part is library full name dose not contain `List` I use this url to find out library full name .

```
[Site url]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

then I change metadate as

> `"__metadata": { "type": 'SP.Data.DocumentsItem' },`

second I added

```
"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE" , "If-Match": "*"
```

to header like:

> ```
>                 headers: {
>                     "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
>                     "X-RequestDigest": contextData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue,
>                     "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
>                     "If-Match": "*"
>                 },
> ```